# Is there a way to figure out the output format in a pandoc lua filter

Tags: filter, lua, pandoc

Lets say I have a code like this:

```
return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text == "any string" then
        return pandoc.RawInline ("latex", "anything")
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

Can i include a if statement that says:
If the output file is latex then use this code and if the output file is html (or not latex) do that...

So I essentially wonder if there is a way of figuring out the output file format within the lua-filter.

Comment: You will have to create a parameter of your own to make this clear to your code. From your snippet here we can't tell what the pandoc settings are, and the point of pandoc is to allow you to output the file in any format it supports once all the content is in it. Perhaps there is a way to do this using pandoc's methods rather than coding your own?

Comment: @JimmyNJ The thing is, I know I can simply make another filter for the case I don't wanna convert to latex. The situation is that I have a specific text in my file, if it is latex it should be changed and if it is not latex it should be deleted. So rather than using two filters I was wondering if there is a way the filter can know what my output file is going to be and filter based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Check out this pandoc lua filters example: https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#center-images-in-latex-and-html-output specifically these lines:

```
if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
...
if FORMAT:match 'html' then
```